# React native vector icon causing the blank screen

Tags: android, react-native, native-base, react-native-vector-icons

I am getting the white screen with Icon component from native-base with the latest version of react-native (0.60.4).

Here is my code

```
<Item floatingLabel error={hasError} style={styles.inputElement}>
          <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "red" }} />
          <Label style={styles.placeHolderStyle}>{placeHolder}</Label>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry={hasSecureTextEntry}
            style={styles.inputPaddingLeft}
            onChangeText={text => this.props.onChangeText(text, key)}
            value={value}
          />
        </Item>
```

If I remove  `<Icon name="ios-menu" style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "red" }} />` tag it works fine.

Also, the above code is working with the older version of react-native(0.55.4)

Answer (score 0):

You might be importing `Icon` from wrong package.I tried your code and it works perfectly fine.

**Output**

[image: Demo]

**Code**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Icon,Item,Label,Input } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <Item error="false">
          <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "red" }} />
          <Label>This is some placeholder</Label>
          <Input
          />
        </Item> 
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Run online**

You can run the above demo online using this [link](https://snack.expo.io/rJ4fus3zS)

Comment: No, I am importing Icon from native-base itself. This is working with older version but not the latest version of react-native.